# Custom List Sort by Part of String

Tags: c#, list, sorting

Apologies if this question has already been answered, but none of my searches returned what I'm looking for.

What I need is a method to sort a list of strings, but the sorting needs to be done by a substring (contains) of the string in the list.

For example:

```
R10.14_R15.2.2b - Upgrade - Even
R10.14_R15.2.2c - Upgrade - Odd
R10.14_R15.2.2 - Upgrade - Prx
```

These are the list items. The order needs to always be (case insensitive):

1. String containing the "PRX" substring.
2. String containing the "ODD" substring.
3. String containing the "EVEN" substring.

So the upper list should look like this after being sorted:

```
R10.14_R15.2.2 - Upgrade - Prx
R10.14_R15.2.2c - Upgrade - Odd
R10.14_R15.2.2b - Upgrade - Even
```

Also, the strings in the list do not always follow the same pattern and the "PRX", "ODD", "EVEN" substring can appear in any place inside of the strings. Additionally the strings do not always contain the same numbers. This is why the ask is to sort by using contains.

I have tried introducing a custom IComparer class, but I had no luck with this approach.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you post what your tried, someone may be able to help you fix it.

Comment: Isn't the logic pretty simple: if the string has `prx`, its "sort value" is 1; if it has `odd`, it's 2, if it has `even`, it's 3; then sort by sort value.

Comment: Everything I tried gave no results and all of the code was deleted.

Comment: If the following string list is not a same pattern or unknown patterns, it is close impossible to sort it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var strings = new List<string>{
    "R10.14_R15.2.2b - Upgrade - Even",
    "R10.14_R15.2.2c - Upgrade - Odd",
    "R10.14_R15.2.2 - Upgrade - Prx"
};

var orderedStrings = strings.OrderBy(s => {
   if(s.Contains("prx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) return 1;
   if(s.Contains("odd", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) return 2;
   if(s.Contains("even", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) return 3;
   return 4;
})
```

Comment: I would use `.EndsWith()` rather than `.Contains()` to avoid edge cases (such as `"somethingOdd - Upgrade - Even"`)

Comment: @Cid A valid concern, but because of "the substring can appear in any place", `.EndsWith()` can't be used.

Comment: @PeterB I guess I missed that part in the question hehe

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<string> stringsToSort = new List<string>
        {
            "R10.14_R15.2.2b - Upgrade - Even",
            "R10.14_R15.2.2c - Upgrade - Odd",
            "R10.14_R15.2.2 - Upgrade - Prx"
        };

        // Define the substrings for sorting
        string[] substrings = { "PRX", "ODD", "EVEN" };

        var sortedList = stringsToSort.OrderBy(str => GetSubstringIndex(str, substrings));

        foreach (var str in sortedList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
        }
    }

    private static int GetSubstringIndex(string input, string[] substrings)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < substrings.Length; i++)
        {
            int index = input.IndexOf(substrings[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            if (index >= 0)
            {
                return index;
            }
        }

        return int.MaxValue;
    }
}
```

In this example, the `OrderBy` method is used to sort the list based on a custom sorting key, which is the index of the first matching substring. The `GetSubstringIndex` method finds the index of the first matching substring in a given input string.